# Call Angular controller from script onload

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

I am trying to update the state of my controller after loading of a script from onload callback.

I load the Google Client API:

```
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/client.js?onload=OnLoadCallback"></script>
```

Then in OnLoadCallback I try to manually bootstrap AngularJS and set the set state on to my controller:

```
function OnLoadCallback() {         
      var $injector = angular.bootstrap(document, ['app']);
      // load required gapi APIs          
      var $controller = $injector.get('$controller');        
      var UserCtrl = $controller('UserCtrl');
      UserCtrl.user.apiLoaded = true;          
};
```

It cannot seem to create a controller with the $scope injected. As the call `$controller('UserCtrl')` fails with:

> Uncaught Error: Unknown provider: $scopeProvider <- $scope

You can see the error by viewing the console in this [Plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/X4iG5iOw1k70fR8NayYc?p=preview).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your usage of controller is wrong, the value has to be set in the scope of the controller

```
function OnLoadCallback() {
  //gapi.client.setApiKey('XXXXXXXXXXXX');
  //gapi.client.load('drive', 'v2', function() {
  var $injector = angular.bootstrap(document, ['app']);
  console.log('Angualar bootstrap complete');         


  var $scope = angular.element('body').scope();
  console.log('Find scope', $scope)

  $scope.$apply(function(){
    $scope.user.apiLoaded = true; 
  })
}
```

Demo: [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/9NJFwPbq1u2ZbRYZWbLL?p=preview)

If you want to get the controller instance, then you will have to manually pass the expected injected values

```
  var $controller = $injector.get('$controller');        
  var UserCtrl = $controller('UserCtrl', {
    $scope: $scope
  });
  console.log(UserCtrl, 'UserCtrl')
```

Demo: [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/hCvbp6qpw8vmbdunh5b3?p=preview)